# For real $a,b$ show using axioms of ordered field that $a < b$ implie $ a^p < b^p$ whenever $ 0 < a < b$ and $p > 0$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, inequality

For real $a,b$ show using axioms of ordered field that $a < b$ implie $ a^p < b^p$ whenever $ 0 < a < b$  and $p > 0$.

I am trying to refresh my memory of maths I learnt 25 years ago. I came across this question in a book but have no idea how to show this.

Comment: julien your answer is not using the requested axioms

Comment: metin on which axiom is your answer based?

Comment: How do you define $x^p$ for $p$ arbitrary real positive number? But if $p$ is a positive integer, you can do, for instance, an induction on $p$ and use only: $x>0$, $y>0$ implies $x+y>0$ and  $xy>0$. Your induction step follows from $b^{p+1}-a^{p+1}=b(b^p-a^p)+a^p(b-a)$.

Comment: yes julien that is part of my problem - Ihave no definition of this before the question and metin this is true  if p is  a natural but if it is  real? Is it possible to prove this just with axioms if p is not natural number?

Answer (score 0):

Show first that if $a < b$ and $c < d$, then $ac < bd$, then apply induction on $p$ (which must be a natural number, otherwise $a^p$ does not make sense).

Comment: if p is a natural number it's not a problem, but the question just says p>0 so I understood it can be any real. I didn't see any definition of a^p before this question.

Comment: You cannot sensibly define $a^p$ in every ordered field. What would be $2^\frac{1}{2} \in \mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: ok but in R it is possible and that is what the question is talking about

Comment: So take any definition of $a^p$ and work with it.

Comment: but if p is real which axioms are relevant to show the relation?